# Stop -Wall -Wextra popup so that a user can compile a program without having to press 'Enter' or 'Esc'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn C++ using VS code in Ubuntu 19.10. I use two C/C++ extensions for this. Now the problem is I have to click the screen twice in order to view the terminal output. Its really getting my nerve. I don't know what that notification is trying to tell, but its really slowing down my performance. How to stop this **Flags** when its clearly not necessary for me now?

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Two extensions which I used for C++ are:

- C/C++ Compile Run by danielpinto8zz6
- C/C++ by Microsoft

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! can you please provide additional information? what extension are you using? what command are you executing to make this input appear?

Comment: @bracco23 I have mentioned the extension name. I have assigned "Alt + A" shortkey to compile & run. Edit: I am just trying to print "Hi P". The whole program is what you see in above the picture.

Comment: sounds like by default `f6` should just run without asking for arguments? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielpinto8zz6.c-cpp-compile-run

Comment: in the long run you'll need to learn to use a proper build system like cmake, single file builds manually invoking the compiler wont last you long in c++

Comment: @AlanBirtles But can't I assign my own shortkey? F6 is too far and I have to press Fn.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Update: I have found another shortkey that say "run with default parameter" and assigned it to "Alt-A". Now its working fine as aspected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an option provided from the *C/C++ Compile Run* extension. It provides several different commands:

1. Compile with default flags
2. Compile with custom flags
3. Compile with default flags and run with default arguments (F6)
4. Compile with custom flags and run with custom arguments (F7)
5. Run with default arguments
6. Run with custom arguments

When custom flags or arguments are mentioned, such input will appear.
As you mentioned in the comment, you remapped one of such command on `Ctrl-A`, and since it is asking for you input I assume it is either 2 or 4 from above. Try using one of the other two compile commands ( depending on if you want to only compile or also run). You can also invoke them manually from the command palette (`Ctrl-Shift-P` and search for one of the commands above.)